# Ruby On Rails Paperclip recommendations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is this the recommended way for handling file uploads?

Comment: Yes, it is *a* recommended way for handling file uploads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CarrierWave File Uploads is a possibility. I don't know if this is the recommended way to do uploads, but it works. You can find a screencast of how to use it at [railscasts.com](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads)